# HTML/CSS How to prevent highlighting text from spanning entire width of page in google chrome

Tags: html, css

Basically when I use Google chrome and highlight text on some websites, the highlight spans the entire width of the browser rather than just highlighting the text. How can CSS be adjusted to make it so that when you highlight text, it only highlights the words rather than span across the entire page as well. A good example to look at is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Try highlighting non-code text in Google chrome and you can see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OCD part of me has wondered this as well: the only thing I've noticed (though this is by no means a comprehensive solution) is that floated elements exhibit the behaviour you're after. [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/V7ahp/) shows a live version (screenshot below) whereby the two `divs` are identical save that one has the declaration `float: left;`, which prevents text highlighting from spanning the entire page.

If it's a big enough issue for you (though I'd say otherwise), you could float your main container to ensure that text highlighting is constrained to it. @solendil's "solution" seems to be massive overkill, introducing a huge usability flaw (how annoying to not be able to select text) for the sake of a minor visual annoyance.

[image: Text highlighting in Chrome]

**Update**: as per @AndreZS's answer, adding a `position` value other than the default `static` also restricts the text highlighting to that element (I think this behaviour has changed in the years since my original answer). It would take someone familiar with WebKit to explain what exactly is going on to trigger the desired behaviour: seems like something to do with the layout of an element and how it is being drawn.

Comment: I agree, thanks for the awesome post. So basically floating elements within elements can solve this, interesting.

Answer (score 7):

In your .css file use `position: relative;` in the the div section that will contain your text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter the machanism of the highlighting algorithm. The highlight spans through paddings and margins, which is annoying sometimes. What you could do is prevent any text selection with CSS

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: didn't know you could do this, I might find a place to use this someday haha, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

```
.content{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V7ahp/4/

The solution by CherryFlavourPez, using float, would lead to further complication like the container won't stretch according to the float div inside.