# Stop selection going to edge of page on multiple lines

Tags: html, css, selection, textselection

When highlighting text to copy, the blue selection goes across the entire page when selecting each line (as you can see in the image below)

[image]

How do you make it so it doesn't go across the page, like in the image below?

[image]

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="maintext">

Welcome/logo

    <div class="headtab">
    About
    </div>

    <p class="info">

   SOME CONTENT

    </p>

  <div class="headtab">
  Requests
  </div>
  <p class="info">
  More content
  </p>

</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
.maintext {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 950px;
    align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    display: block;
}
p.info {
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 150%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    display: block;
}
.headtab {
    margin-left: -110px;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: #FF8100;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    line-heihgt: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline; 
    /* The following stopping of text selection is from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018324/how-do-i-stop-highlighting-of-a-div-element-when-double-clicking-on */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

/* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239129/html-css-how-to-prevent-highlighting-text-from-spanning-entire-width-of-page-in

Comment: I guess you could be right. I did just try the examples on there and it works to an extent

Answer (score 1):

You must use some sort of block tag such as `<div>` to put the text into.  THe highlight will only be as big as the `div` the texts sits in.

Comment: It's all wrapped inside but it still goes over

Comment: Hmm, I will continue to look into it. That should have worked.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox. I will edit the question to show the code

Comment: Edited
Not sure at all what I am doing wrong. Such a noobie question, but I've never really needed to do this before

Comment: as DACrosby said this is a duplicate question and the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239129/html-css-how-to-prevent-highlighting-text-from-spanning-entire-width-of-page-in  Good Luck

Comment: Ah yes, he's right. I added  position: relative; to .maintext and it works now.